# React - Internet explorer 11 input loses focus after first onchange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, antd

I have come across a very strange issue that I can't wrap my head around.
I'm currently working with an create-react-app using react 16.3 and Antd 3.11 framework and I have created a table which inside it's header column renders a  component with an onChange event attached.

The issue comes when I focus the input for the first time.

I lose focus on first key event, and afterwards when I click the field again, it remains focused until I click something else.

Here is the example I have been using:
https://ant.design/components/table/

and the code that follows.

```
import {
  Table, Input, Button, Icon,
} from 'antd';

const data = [{
  key: '1',
  name: 'John Brown',
  age: 32,
  address: 'New York No. 1 Lake Park',
}, {
  key: '2',
  name: 'Joe Black',
  age: 42,
  address: 'London No. 1 Lake Park',
}, {
  key: '3',
  name: 'Jim Green',
  age: 32,
  address: 'Sidney No. 1 Lake Park',
}, {
  key: '4',
  name: 'Jim Red',
  age: 32,
  address: 'London No. 2 Lake Park',
}];

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    searchText: '',
  };

  handleSearch = (selectedKeys, confirm) => () => {
    confirm();
    this.setState({ searchText: selectedKeys[0] });
  }

  handleReset = clearFilters => () => {
    clearFilters();
    this.setState({ searchText: '' });
  }

  render() {
    const columns = [{
      title: 'Name',
      dataIndex: 'name',
      key: 'name',
      filterDropdown: ({
        setSelectedKeys, selectedKeys, confirm, clearFilters,
      }) => (
        <div className="custom-filter-dropdown">
          <Input
            ref={ele => this.searchInput = ele}
            placeholder="Search name"
            value={selectedKeys[0]}
            onChange={e => setSelectedKeys(e.target.value ? [e.target.value] : [])}
            onPressEnter={this.handleSearch(selectedKeys, confirm)}
          />
          <Button type="primary" onClick={this.handleSearch(selectedKeys, confirm)}>Search</Button>
          <Button onClick={this.handleReset(clearFilters)}>Reset</Button>
        </div>
      ),
      filterIcon: filtered => <Icon type="smile-o" style={{ color: filtered ? '#108ee9' : '#aaa' }} />,
      onFilter: (value, record) => record.name.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase()),
      onFilterDropdownVisibleChange: (visible) => {
        if (visible) {
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.searchInput.focus();
          });
        }
      },
      render: (text) => {
        const { searchText } = this.state;
        return searchText ? (
          <span>
            {text.split(new RegExp(`(${searchText})`, 'gi')).map((fragment, i) => (
              fragment.toLowerCase() === searchText.toLowerCase()
                ? <span key={i} className="highlight">{fragment}</span> : fragment // eslint-disable-line
            ))}
          </span>
        ) : text;
      },
    }, {
      title: 'Age',
      dataIndex: 'age',
      key: 'age',
    }, {
      title: 'Address',
      dataIndex: 'address',
      key: 'address',
      filters: [{
        text: 'London',
        value: 'London',
      }, {
        text: 'New York',
        value: 'New York',
      }],
      onFilter: (value, record) => record.address.indexOf(value) === 0,
    }];
    return <Table columns={columns} dataSource={data} />;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, mountNode);
```

And the css that follows to that:

```
.custom-filter-dropdown {
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

.custom-filter-dropdown input {
  width: 130px;
  margin-right: 8px;
}

.custom-filter-dropdown button {
  margin-right: 8px;
}

.highlight {
  color: #f50;
}
```

To quickly sum up things i've come to understand.

- The table rerenders the filterDropDown prop, filterIcon on every
  keystroke.
- The class component where the table is within does not rerender or
  trigger(componentDidUpdate)
- This works perfectly in Chrome, FireFox, Edge and the sample works in
  IE11 on antds website. however not in my app.
- All antd  fields and regular  fields which are rendered in my own components does not have this problem in any browser.
- Rendering the input components outside the render function does not
  work since it is not my component that rerenders it is the table component that triggers it's own update events
- I have also tried to change -ms-user-select: settings to different attributes to see weather that had an effect or not. fact was it only made it worse.
- I've tried to set input value as a state value to make it a controlled component, however when componentDidUpdate triggers and I programtically set .focus on my input it sets caretIndex lenght-1 instead of behind text. (I have manually tried to override selectionStart and SelectionEnd but without success

I'm sort of running out of ideas since what I have come to understand is that some other component is stealing the focus of my input box, however I have not been able to find the element even though I've used 
document.activeElement in almost every method and lifecycle event I could think of. All events point to the 'a' Input field having focus (not sure if this is the old or new one created, however I think it's the old one).

I have tried my best to explain my scenario and I hope someone out there in the world has come across a similar issue.

**UPDATE**: 
antd reasonly changed their table component so the example is a bit different on the webpage, however issue still remains the same.

Comment: I'd recommend recreating this in [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/dashboard), that way SO users will be able to recreate the problem themselves.

Comment: CodeSandBox cannot show examples in internet explorer. Waste of time.

Comment: What about stackblitz, plnkr, repl, etc.

Comment: Phix I will check up on that. Thank you guys for the advice.

Comment: still no answers?

Answer (score 2):

I hade the same behavior on IE11.

Could fix it with an additional onBlur on the Input field, that just set the focus to the currentTarget.

```
onBlurHandler = (e: React.FocusEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    e.currentTarget.focus();
};
```