# React input field re-renders after onChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, forms

Hello I'm sorry for asking a question that's probably been answered numerous times. I'm new to `react` and `react-redux`.

I have a form with about 70 input fields. So I need to find the best practice to solve this for all my fields. This problem seems to only happen in IE and Edge. When imputing data into an input field the input field loses focus after every character typed.

I was reading solutions, I tried adding a key to the input field that didn't work. I also tried moving the input field out of the return function still no success. I'm aware I may have tried doing these solutions wrong. I also read it may be how the application is routed.

Here is my code. I stripped it down to only show 1 input field, but keep in mind I have about 70 of these.

```
import * as React from 'react';

export class Products extends React.Component<{}, {
    product1: string,
}> {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            product1: '',
        };

        this.handleChangeproduct1 = this.handleChangeproduct1.bind(this);   
    }

    handleChangeproduct1(event) {
        const { value } = event.target;
        this.setState({ product1: value }); 
    }   

    public render(): React.ReactElement<{}> {
        //I tried putting the input outside of the render
        let example;
        example = <div>
                <label>
                    Product 1
                </label>
                <input
                    value={this.state.product1}
                    onChange={this.handleChangeproduct1}
                    type="text"
                    className="phone validate"
                    name="Product 1"
                    maxLength={120}
                    key="testing"
                />
            <span>Name plus contact name and email or phone number if new vendor.</span>
        </div>;        

        return (
            <div>
                <label>
                    Product 1
                </label>
                <input
                    value={this.state.product1}
                    onChange={this.handleChangeproduct1}
                    type="text"
                    className="phone validate"
                    name="Product 1"
                    maxLength={120}
                    key="testing"
                />
                <span>Name plus contact name and email or phone number if new vendor.</span>

              //I'm showing both examples at one time
              {example}

            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I also tried changing my route from the first line to second line:

```
<Route path="/product" component={Product} />
<Route path="/product" render={() => <Product/>} />
```

EDIT: I FOUND the input that's causing the issue. But no idea how to fix it. I'm using 'react-currency-input` so that some of the fields have money format. When I remove this input all my fields work. Any idea?

```
handleChangeEstimatedDelivery = async (event, maskedvalue, floatvalue) => {
    await this.setState({EstimatedDelivery: maskedvalue});

    this.handleChangeEstimatedTotal();      
}       

<CurrencyInput
    value={this.state.EstimatedDelivery}
    onChange={this.handleChangeEstimatedDelivery}
    className="phone validate"
    name="Estimated Delivery"
    prefix="$"                                              
/>
```

Comment: your example does not have this problem, you will need to provide reproducible example

Comment: Are you using local component state, or connected to a redux store with form field state there?

Comment: @DrewReese Yes I believe it's a local component state. I'm not connected to anything

Comment: @Aleksey this component is over 1k lines long. It's happening to all of the input fields. It works perfect on Chrome. It's IE and Edge giving me issues. Problem is most of my users use Edge

Comment: Edge is technically chromium based now, but if they are still using M$ then they may still be using some old product. It'd be nice if the acceptable answer was to ditch IE/Edge.

Comment: What's the Edge version?

Comment: @JózefPodlecki Microsoft Edge 44.17763.831.0

Comment: @DrewReese I wish that could be the answer! lol. Is there really no fix that we can preform for this for edge?

Comment: Can't reproduce on `44.18362.449.0` Is it just click on the input field and type something?

Comment: @JózefPodlecki correct. I have to re-click the field every time to add another character. Am I able to add anything in the change handle to console out what's causing this?

Comment: [There was similar question asked before but workaround is quite ridiculous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53780602/react-internet-explorer-11-input-loses-focus-after-first-onchange)

Comment: @JózefPodlecki I found the field that's causing my issue can you look at my edit?